# Bitmaps and Android Heap

Tags: android, bitmap, heap-memory, surfaceview, ddms

My app uses some bitmaps with a SurfaceView. For bitmaps that a recalled often I stored them as class fields, i.e. when my extension of SurfaceView instance is created I have

```
bitmap_puppyicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.puppy);
```

Where bitmap_puppyicon is a class variable of my extended SurfaceView. WHich means, I think, it is on the heap.

For bitmaps that are used once or twice or so, I created them on the fly in the onDraw() method.

I checked out the heap in DDMS and felt I could afford to store more bitmaps as class variables instead of creating them in onDraw().

To my surprise the heap size went down a few percentage points after doing this. Have I misunderstood something? Why would the heap get smaller with more bitmaps stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It use skia under the hood, and heap is not the place where bitmaps live, In the heap you have links to bitmaps only